# how to store the bit string in array?

Tags: c++, c

how to count number of occurrences of 1 in a 8 bit string. such as 10110001.
bit string is taken from user. like 10110001
what type of array should be used to store this bit string in c?

Comment: If it's that short, just use whatever you find easiest to use.

Comment: would you plz write  code for that operation. so that bit string can be used to count occurrences of "1".

Comment: Use [`std::bitset`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772083/how-to-store-the-bit-string-in-array/5772098#5772098).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short and simple. Use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)(C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  std::bitset<8> mybitstring;
  std::cin >> mybitstring;
  std::cout << mybitstring.count(); // returns the number of set bits
}
```

[Online Test at Ideone](http://ideone.com/LzYc5)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array at all, use  a std::string. This gives you the possibility of better error handling. You can write code like:

```
bitset <8> b;
if ( cin >> b ) {
    cout << b << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

but there is no way of finding out which character caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably use an `unsigned int` to store those bits in C.

If you're using GCC then you can use `__builtin_popcount` to count the one bits:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)`
>   Returns the number of 1-bits in x.

This should resolve to a single instruction on CPUs that support it too.

Answer (score 0):

From hacker's delight:

```
For machines that don't have this instruction, a good way to count the number
of 1-bits is to first set each 2-bit field equal to the sum of the two single
bits that were originally in the field, and then sum adjacent 2-bit fields,
putting the results in each 4-bit field, and so on.
```

so, if `x` is an integer:

```
x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);
x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) + ((x >>16) & 0x0000FFFF);
```

`x` will now contain the number of 1 bits. Just adapt the algorithm with 8 bit values.